# Java For Each with a getter

Tags: java, c#, performance, for-loop

It's been a while since I last used Java, as I'm primarily a C# developer. To get back into the game, I was working on a very simple application to touch on most of the key features of the language. I ran across the following problem:

```
for (Player player : teamRed.getPlayers()) {
    System.out.format("> %s\n", player.getName());
}
```

Where `getPlayers()` is defined as follows:

```
public Iterable<Player> getPlayers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.players);
}
```

At some point in the past, either C# or Java had a performance issue when you used a getter in your for each like this, as it would execute the method every iteration. I cannot find anything about this anymore, so I wonder:

**Has Java ever been subject to this issue, or was it the case for C# only?**

Personally, I feel the compiler should be smart enough to optimize this properly and actually store the result of `getPlayers` in a temporary variable before iterating over it. But if not, I have no trouble helping the compiler a hand :P

Comment: Look up the enhanced for statement [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), look for "The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form". You will find that the `getPlayers()` method is called just once, by specification.

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate. I recall it was specifically related to using a method to retrieve the list you want to iterate over. The linked question uses direct access to a defined array.

Comment: I don't remember Java ever having such a problem (since before 1.2) and I'm having a hard time believing C# would have suffered from such an elementary oversight as well.

Comment: @LennardFonteijn That's why it says *possible* duplicate :)

Comment: Note that wrapping `this.players` in an unmodifiable list is mostly redundant: it just means that the list can't be modified through the returned reference - but it could be through anything holding a reference to the list directly, like the instance owning the players list. You may as well just return the list directly - the return type is `Iterable`, which is itself unmodifiable. (Or return a copy of the list).

Comment: @Kayaman Reading all comments now, I think this was the case when you iterated over a LINQ query in C# that was not persisted yet (`ToList()`, `ToArray()`), not Java as you mention :)

Comment: @AndyTurner The `getPlayers()` is part of a class that does not expose the players-list by any other means, it's completely private (and final for that matter). I purposely return an unmodifiable list to force people to use the `addPlayer()` method, also part of the class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will store the iterator (from calling the `iterator()` method on the `Iterable`) that it loops over, so the `getPlayers()` method will only be called once. You could observe this using the below adaptation of `getPlayers()`

```
public Iterable<Player> getPlayers() {
    System.out.println("getPlayers() called");
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.players);
}
```

When running your first code snippet, "getPlayers() called" would only be printed once.

Check the `Iterable` docs for more detail (notably the `iterator()` method): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: Very simple yet effective. You do have a typo in your "output", but SO won't let me edit just one character :P Also thanks for all other comments.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the typos